# CSS3 transition with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this Webpage on which with mouse over, the element rotates and goes back to original position on mouseout.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
transition:width 2s;
-moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
}

div:hover
{
width:300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer.</p>

<div></div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Now Is it possible to trigger this transition using JavaScript and not the defualt hover function. I tried by creating two different class names but it just dosent work even if i do it by adding delay and changing the class. Is there anyway to do such a transition with Javascript??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is fire a change the style of the element you want to modify when particular events happen.  Also, I changed the DOCTYPE to use HTML5.  Give this a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
div.sample1
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
transition:width 2s;
-moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
}

div.sample1:hover
{
width:300px;
}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doStuff(obj,boolStateChange)
{
    console.log('test');
    if (boolStateChange==true)
    {
    obj.style.cssText = "width:300px;height:100px;background:green;transition:width 2s;-moz-transition:width 2s;-webkit-transition:width 2s;-o-transition:width 2s;";

    }
    else
    {
    obj.style.cssText = "width:100px;height:100px;background:green;transition:width 2s;-moz-transition:width 2s;-webkit-transition:width 2s;-o-transition:width 2s;";
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer.</p>

<div class="sample1"></div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

<br/><br/><br/>

<div id="javaHover" style="background-color:green;width:100px;height:100px;" onMouseOver="doStuff(this,true);" onMouseOut="doStuff(this,false);"></div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the Javascript transition effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are a champion. Thank you a bazillion times, thank you so so much!!

Answer (score 1):

what do you think about this:
http://jsfiddle.net/scrRe/ ?

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/scrRe/3/

Comment: yes but is there anyway to avoid jQuery, Im sure it must be simple. I may be missing something. I just need to change the CSS from hover and call it from some javascript function but what is it exactly what i am missing??

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.width = '300px';
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUgJy/).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `:hover` selector then. Use JavaScript events.

for example:

CSS:

```
#box
{
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: height 1s, width 1s;
  -moz-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s, width 1s; 
  -o-transition: height 1s, width 1s;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
 var element = document . getElementById ( "box" ) ;


 element . addEventListener
 (
     "click",
     function ()
     {
         this . style . width = "200px" ;
     }
 ) ;

 element . addEventListener
 (
    "dblclick",
     function ()
     {
         this . style . height = "200px" ;
     }
 ) ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gSZD/

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [CSSAnimation](http://ryanflorence.com/cssanimation), which is a JavaScript library that allows you to trigger animations with JavaScript while utilizing CSS to do the actual animation.

Here's an example from the documentation ([try it](http://jsfiddle.net/rpflorence/yk9gW/)):

```js
var element = document.getElementById('some-el'),
    transition = new Transition(element),
    transform = new Transform(element);

transition.set({
  property: 'transform',
  'timing-function': 'ease-in',
  duration: '2s'
});

transform.rotate(720).scale(2);
```